# Access between database and web front-end servers of SharePoint 2019 farm

Tags: sql-server, iis, firewall, f5, sharepoint-2019

I am a developer with limited knowledge of SharePoint Administration. We have a SharePoint 2019 multi-tier farm.

- 1 App with Central Admin
- 1 App with Search
- 1 F5 Firewall between App and Web Servers
- 2 Web Front End Servers (WFE)

Everything was good until we have deployed a new Publishing Portal with Anonymous Access enabled. As we are going public our infra and infosec team raises concern over the Web Front End Servers' access to DB while the public-facing WFE server should have only access to the Application server and the application server should only have the right to communicate with DB, which I think is correct.

However, there is Microsoft documentation that suggests the required architecture but is only applicable to SharePoint 2013 farm. The below image shows that WFE servers have only App Server Access and no direct DB Access to WFE servers.

[image: The image shows that WFE servers have only App Server Access and no direct DB Access to WFE servers.]

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/multiple-servers-for-a-three-tier-farm) link suggested the above image architecture.

Simplifying the issue I have SharePoint 2019 Farm for which I want to block the WFE Server's access to the db Servers, I only want to allow the SharePoint Application Server to be accessed by the WFE servers.

Comment: What is your question here, and what does it have to do with programming? Everything you seem to be talking about here is about Sharepoint and it's authentication model(s); that is completely off topic for [so].

Comment: The question is how to configure web front end server if we block the Db access, as you can see in this image [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsecureanycloud.com%2Fsharepoint-2019-on-cloud-technical-support-cloud-help-azure-aws-opensource-cognosys%2F&psig=AOvVaw0j3Tifchjgu_ZfUkC6I8z7&ust=1636808305638000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCIii6KPwkvQCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ) we have to provide the Database details to configure the Web Front end Servers.

Comment: That doesn't actually tell me what *your* question is, and now it looks like you're talking about networking, which is completely off-topic of [so]; it's for programming based questions.

Comment: Yes, it's not a programming-based question. it is comprised of Network Security and Infrastructure and SharePoint Farm Architecture.

Comment: Yes, I Guess, I also posted it on SharePoint Stackexchange but no help. I think might get help from StackOverflow.